# For Good SEO, If I Have www.domain.com Should I Also Have www.subdomain.domain.com?

Tags: web, dns, seo, subdomain

Should subdomains have a www if the main domain has a www?  For example:  if I have www.domain.com, should I also have www.subdomain.domain.com? I have a website where Siteliner.com did an analysis and they said there are inconsistencies within the site regarding www.  The only inconsisitency there is, is that the main site is www but the subdomains are not... what should I do from the point of view of good SEO?

Comment: Your main domain is prefixed www, your subdomain is prefixed subdomain. In effect - they are both subs of the main domain. Why would you add another level to subdomain.

Comment: This question is off topic for this site. This site is for questions about *computer programming*. It is also for questions about *programming computers*. Questions about *writing computer software* are also on topic, as are questions about *tools for modifying source code*.

Comment: I think this may be off-topic because it is about SEO, not programming.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In reality, for any site facing the internet, you are better off just having A records or hosts. I'm not sure of the context of your question, but if you want to make life easy for yourself, use hosts.

Example: 
All the following A records can be visited from a client on the internet if port 80 is open on them. A Search engine running a crawl search would have no issues with SEO either, given that you have registered everything correctly.

www.domain.com IN A 10.10.10.10

myserver.domain.com IN A 10.10.10.11

From an SEO standpoint, the following subdomains don't match the FQDN you would have initially registered with your search provider and could cause issues.

www.subdomain.domain.com IN A 10.10.11.1

The search engine crawler would possible take issue with the fact that you have a World Wide Web (www) server running on a subdomain of your top level domain.
Usually subdomains are used as intranet gateways, or other sites. It's not wrong, by any means, just not usually the done thing.

So, maybe this is why Siteliner is saying there may be issues.

I would also recommend checking your DNS entries on dnsstuff.com

Comment: Thank you.  That helps a lot.  I now understand how a "host" is used and I also understand that adding www to a subdomain could muddy-up how I have defined my domain name, from an SEO point of view.  Based on this, I will not use www in front of my subdomains.

Comment: I didnt consider the question blatantly off-topic, the user was in my experience just attempting to explain something they were unfamiliar with.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the feedback guys. Understood. I'll stay away from these topics in future.